# Download anchor of PDF file fetched with ajax in functions.php not working - WordPress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, pdf, download

In my page, I'm calling a function located in functions.php that uses AJAX to get the post types I need (it's a sorting function).

As a result, I get this response: `$response .= '<a class="cs-centredoc__button download" href="' . get_field('cs-file') . '" download>' . $download . '</a><a class="cs-centredoc__button see" href="' . get_field('cs-file') . '" target="_file">' . $see . '</a>';`

The first link is to download, and the second one is to see the PDF online.

My issue is that the download is not happening. It opens the document (in the same tab..) and that's it. I used the exact same code somewhere else, without the AJAX (so directly in my .php file) and it's working fine.

A bit like you can't select an element that you dynamically created in jQuery like this `$(".the-element").on("click", function...` you need to do it so: `$(document).on('click', '.the-element', function() {...`  Could it be the same thing for an ajax element?

I've tried using `window.location.href = destinationURL` and I get the same result (PDF opening in the same page).

Comment: Don't see how AJAX would have _anything_ to do with this. Links with the `download` attribute only work as such, if the `href` points to the same origin, as the page this link is getting used on - that the case here?